# String bracket/assignment and a shell command

Tags: ruby

I am using chef. Why doesn't this work?

```
someString[aSearchString]= `pwd`
```

For me, `aSearchString` does not end up getting replaced.  I have to execute `pwd` on a separate line into a variable, and then use that to do the replacement.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: what are you trying to replace? I'm sorry but question is not quite clear.

Comment: `someString.sub(aSearchString, `pwd`)` ?

Comment: I'm just trying to replace a string in my string with the current working directory path.  Turns out it was working, but I was expecting this to replace all occurrences of the search string, when it seems that only the first instance is replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
some_string.gsub('search_string', `pwd`)

>> s="./asd"   #=> "./asd"
>> s.gsub('.', `pwd`) #=> "/home/rahul\n/asd"
>> s.gsub('.', `pwd`.chop) #=> "/home/rahul/asd"   #chop because 'pwd` adds \n at end
>> s.gsub!('.', `pwd`.chop)  #=> "/home/rahul/asd" #inplace
```

Benchmark:

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.12 :005 > my_bm(1000){"/./././.".gsub(".", `pwd`)}
   user     system      total        real
0.040000   0.760000   0.800000 (  2.690505)
=> nil 
ree-1.8.7-2011.12 :006 > my_bm(1000){c=`pwd`;"/./././.".gsub(".", c)}
   user     system      total        real
0.140000   0.660000   0.800000 (  2.692811)
=> nil 
ree-1.8.7-2011.12 :007 > my_bm(1000){"/./././.".gsub(".", `pwd`)}
   user     system      total        real
0.090000   0.720000   0.810000 (  2.705673)
=> nil 
ree-1.8.7-2011.12 :008 > my_bm(1000){c=`pwd`;"/./././.".gsub(".", c)}
   user     system      total        real
0.090000   0.720000   0.810000 (  2.688737)
=> nil
```

Comment: This will execute `pwd` for every instance of `'search_string'`. It might be more efficient to capture the output into a variable, then sub that.

Comment: @tadman It won't bcz gsub is method on string so it will execute {pwd} only for one time. Its more like passing argument to method. thats it.

Comment: @tadman I have edited answer with benchmark. Both take same time. Bcz its a normal function call.

Comment: Ah, right you are. Good catch on `chop` as well.